# How to relate a lambda function with a def function in Python?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I just enrolled to a Data Science training course. In the pre-work for Data Science, there is some "basic" python stuff and I am learning the **def functions**, as well as the **lambda functions**.

Below you can find a combination of both, but I have no idea how it actually works and what is the process flow.

The code I do not understand how it works is the following:

```py
def func(x):
    return lambda y: (x + y + 1)

def func1(x):
    return lambda y : (func(x)(x)+y+1)

print(func1(3)(1))
```

And the returned value is:

```py
9
```

Comment: Ok, so there must be something you understand. Can you at least point out all of that and we can fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(x):
    return lambda y: (x + y + 1)

def func1(x):
    return lambda y : (func(x)(x)+y+1)

print(func1(3)(1))
```

Functions in `python` are 1st class citizens, therefore you might create functions which `return`s function. This feature is used here in *both* `def`s. Note that call look as follows

```
func(x)(x)
func1(3)(1)
```

as first parts (`func(x)` and `func1(3)`) `return`s functions which are then called with single arguments (`x` and `1`)

Answer (score 0):

This is purposefully convoluted code and you will not see such a code in real life. And if you do, then run away from that company or project as fast as you can. And regarding to your understanding, try to expand the function calls the same way as you expand mathematical formulas. If you understand what lambda is, then it should be easy to expand this step by step.

So we want to evaluate this `func1(3)(1)`. Lets dig into it step by step.

Step1: Lets' start with the first part:

`func1(3)` ==> `lambda y: (func(x)(x) + y + 1)` where `x` is `3` ==> `lambda y: (func(3)(3) + y + 1)`

Step2: Let's have a look at this part:

`func(3)` ==> `lambda y: (x + y + 1)` where `x` is `3` ==> `lambda y: (3 + y + 1)`

Step3: Now let's go one step further:

`func(3)(3)` ==> `(3 + y + 1)` where `y` is `3` ==> `3 + 3 + 1` ==> `7`

Step 4: now let's get back to the result from step 1:

`lambda y: (func(3)(3) + y + 1)` ==> `lambda y: (7 + y + 1)`

Step 5: and now lets put this all together:

`func1(3)(1)` ==> `(7 + y + 1)` where `y` is `1` ==> `9`

Answer (score 0):

i will try my best.

im experimenting with the code and do something with the first function
it will look like this :

```
def func(x):
    return lambda y: (x + y + 1)
print(func(3)(1))
```

the interesting part is you actually can put the lambda value beside the the function value so lambda value will be 1 and function value will be 3 then the result would be:

3 + 1 + 1 = 5

now the hard part that take me long to quite understand it
because its tricky.

```
def func(x):
    return lambda y: (x + y + 2)
print(func(3)(1))



def func1(x):
    return lambda y : (func(x)(x)+y+1)
print(func1(4)(1))
```

i see something tricky in this code, like:

4 + 4 + 1 + 1 = 10

like where is the other value to get the number to be 12
and that is where it get the value from the above function that is 2 to be putted in the function and the result would be:

4 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 12

that's what i know.

now my brain is hot.